# Check availability of Google App Invites

Tags: android, google-app-invites

When I call to startActivityForResult to show Google App Invites activity, I get an ActivityNotFoundException: "No Activity found to handle Intent act=com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ACTION_APP_INVITE"

Is there a way to check if I can use App Invites in a device before try to launch it? (I don't want to only check if device can handle com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ACTION_APP_INVITE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the reason because I was receiving the error is that Google Play Services were not installed.

So I can check availability using:

```
GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to check if there is any third party activity available to handle your intent.

Checkout the method

[queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

and it is [recommended by Google](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#Verify)

Comment: Thanks. But I think it would be better to check if Play Services are installed.

Comment: This method is generalized and can be used while starting any third party activity. It is not restricted to Google Play Services only. And yes you can check for Google play services availability and request user to update or install play services.

Comment: please add a code sample of how to use this not just linking it to the docs

Comment: PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;